# Cookies from requests to Selenium

Tags: python, cookies, session-cookies

I am trying to pass cookies from requests to selenium.

In other words, need to get cookies to the json format, that antidetect browsers can accept.

`s=requsts.Session()`

`s.get(url)`

`session.cookies.get_dict()` geting requests coookies

example cookies format from request session : `{'_ga': 'GA1.2.1031912414.1674375073', '_gid': 'GA1.2.1505665869.1674375073', '_sess': 'anything', 'auth_token': 'some', 'ct': 'something', 'gt': '1617072368437919744', 'guest_id': 'v1%3A167437506907088403', 'guest_id_ads': 'v1%3A167437506907088403', 'guest_id_marketing': 'some', 'kst': 'some', 'personalization_id': 'some', 'ggid': 'some', 'lang': 'en'}`

example cookies format needed: `[{"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1829282891, "httpOnly": true, "name": "auth_token", "path": "/", "sameSite": "None", "secure": true, "value": "some"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1829282892, "httpOnly": false, "name": "cst", "path": "/", "sameSite": "Lax", "secure": true, "value": "some"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1671613650, "httpOnly": false, "name": "gt", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "1605444830477574144"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1734674898, "httpOnly": false, "name": "_ga", "path": "/", "secure": false, "value": "GA1.2.1905152547.1671602853"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1718863691, "httpOnly": true, "name": "kst", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "some"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1671689298, "httpOnly": false, "name": "_gid", "path": "/", "secure": false, "value": "GA1.2.1382937366.1671602853"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1734674843, "httpOnly": false, "name": "personalization_id", "path": "/", "sameSite": "None", "secure": true, "value": "some"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1703138898, "httpOnly": false, "name": "twid", "path": "/", "sameSite": "None", "secure": true, "value": "some"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1734674843, "httpOnly": false, "name": "guest_id", "path": "/", "sameSite": "None", "secure": true, "value": "some"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1734674843, "httpOnly": false, "name": "guest_id_ads", "path": "/", "sameSite": "None", "secure": true, "value": "some"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "httpOnly": true, "name": "r_sess", "path": "/", "secure": true, "value": "some"}, {"domain": ".any.com", "expiry": 1734674843, "httpOnly": false, "name": "guest_id_marketing", "path": "/", "sameSite": "None", "secure": true, "value": "some"}]`

maybe there is some *smart* workaround? I am using python.

Answer (score 0):

please could you try the following:

```
import requests
import http.cookiejar
import urllib
import json

def function():
  url=www.example.com
  cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
  url_opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie_jar))
  url_opener.open(url)
  for cookie in cookie_jar:
     obtained_cookie=cookie.name, cookie.value
     cookie_json=json.dumps(obtained_cookie, indent=2)
     print(cookie_json)
```